# A decent IDE / code-editor addon for blender

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

Can anyone recommend some editor or IDE addon for making python scripting a little less cumbersome than using the built in text editor?

I really miss stuff like suggestion of function names etc. that pretty much any IDE or code editor has these days.

Is there any specific addon or editor that you find ideal when it comes to blender scripting?

I am a newbie when it comes to Blender and also when it comes to the Python language so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: There is a paid addon on cgmarket https://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/code-autocomplete/

Comment: This question belongs on  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ because it is asking for a recommendation of an IDE, and is hardly about blender.

Comment: Since python does not declare data types it is difficult to analyze the source code for an IDE. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is powerful and available for free.To enable code inspection for the blender api you would have to [build blender as a module](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) or create a stub.

Comment: There you go edited so it now belongs here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a paid add-on on Blender Market: [Link](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/code-autocomplete/), but the add-on is also available for free from GitHub here: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/code_autocomplete. You would just need to use the green "Clone or Download" button and choose to download it as a .zip. Note that Jacques Lucke says [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-auto-completion-in-blenders-text-editor/627858):

> You can buy it in the BlenderMarket but it is also freely available on github.
>   Buying the addon entitles you to better support when you have questions and helps to ensure that I can continue working on my addons!

And another free one: [Link](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2014/10/addon-addon-template-generator.html)

Eclipse related: [Link](http://daniepstein.com/daniepstein/tutorials/python-blender-and-a-bit-of-debuggery/)